# ElasticSearch empty sub bucket list in filter aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a multilevel aggregation with filter, and I'm getting empty results for buckets which don't have matches for the filter. I want to elimnate those buckets.

I tried specifying

Docs + Query

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "languages": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "sub_type.keyword": "fdsfsd"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sub_type": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "sub_type.keyword",
                 "min_doc_count": 1
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "language",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "languages": {
            "doc_count": 0,
            "sub_type": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type.keyword",
        "min_doc_count": 1, 
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "languages": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "sub_type.keyword": "fdsfsd"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sub_type": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "sub_type.keyword",
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Changes**

Specify **min_doc_count** at top level aggrtation.

Comment: "key": "language",
          "doc_count": 1,

You are getting minimum 1 doc count in your lanuage aggrtation.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear - I don't want the whole thing. I want to get languages that have sub aggregations that match the filter